# Remove string matches from another variable in Bash

Tags: bash

I have a string like this:

```
austria rome italy venice london
```

I want to remove certain strings from above string:

```
rome venice
```

which should result in `austria italy london`.

I found sed but could not get it to work, also tried:

```
diff <(echo "string1") <(echo "string2") | grep "^<" | cut -c3-
```

but it also does not produce the desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `sed` with extended regex to remove all unwanted words:

```
$ places='austria rome italy venice london'
$ echo $places|sed -E 's/austria|italy|london//g'
 rome  venice
```

Where:

- `-E` is extended regex, to match multiple words via **OR**
  (`|`) operator
- `g` matches **all** instances of found words

**Update**:
Previous answer left leading whitespace that can be removed via:

```
$ echo $places|sed -E 's/austria|italy|london//g'|sed 's/^[ ]*//'
rome  venice
```

As Kristianmitk pointed out, double spaces created by a removed word's leading and ending spaces can be replaced by a single space:

```
$ echo $places|sed -E 's/austria|italy|london//g'|sed 's/^[ ]*//;s/  / /g'
rome venice
```

Alternatively, you can remove unwanted words **and** all trailing space after them:

```
$ echo $places|sed -E 's/austria *|italy *|london *//g'
rome venice
```

Comment: It gives me sed: 1: "s/austria|italy|london//ig": bad flag in substitute command: 'i'
Update: my bad, I had a typo.

Comment: ```i``` was for a case-insensitive search. I've tested it and it doesn't give that error, however, I've removed it from my answer as it isn't relevant to your question.

Comment: You are actually replacing the woulds by a whitespace. Add `;s/  / /g` at the end of the regex to avoid that

Comment: @Kristianmitk replacing woulds by a whitespace? as in?

Comment: words* - the result contains two whitespaces between the words, not one like the input string

Comment: @Kristianmitk Thanks for spotting that, but doesn't ```s/ / /g``` replace a space with a space? Shouldn't it be ```s/ //g``` to remove the space?

Comment: you are totally right - should not type from my phone - down below in my answer its correct: `s/  / /g` - replacing double spaces by a single one. `s/ //g` would remove all spaces which would lead to a single long word (e.g `romevenice`)

Comment: @Kristianmitk Good point, thanks for spotting this, I've updated my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

With `sed` a simple one-liner:

```
echo "austria rome italy venice london" | sed 's/rome//g;s/venice//g;s/  / /g'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert your single line strings to one word per line, use `grep -v`, then convert back to a one-line string with `paste -s`. To avoid problems with word splitting, we first read the words into arrays:

```
$ str1='austria rome italy venice london'
$ str2='rome venice'
$ read -a arr1 <<< "$str1"
$ read -a arr2 <<< "$str2"
$ printf '%s\n' "${arr1[@]}" | grep -vf <(printf '%s\n' "${arr2[@]}") | paste -sd ' '
austria italy london
```

Alternatively, you could use `tr`:

```
tr ' ' '\n' <<< "$str1" | grep -vf <(tr ' ' '\n' <<< "$str2") | paste -sd ' '
```

Notice that after assigning to strings, this solves the general problem of "remove from one list of words all words contained in another list of words".

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the most elegant solution as it stands, but may guide you in a more specific bash-only solution.

```
x=(austria rome italy venice london)
remove_from_x() { for i in "${!x[@]}"; do if [ "${x[$i]}" = "$1" ]; then unset x[$i]; fi; done }

remove_from_x rome
echo ${x[@]}     # -> austria italy venice london
remove_from_x venice
echo ${x[@]}     # -> austria italy london
```